# Html Special Chars PHP

Tags: php, html, tags, char, strip

fm API to get event discription, venue name etc...

Now sometimes I get special chars back like: ' é à , but they show up scrabled.

So how can I display them properly? Also with the descrioption I get html-tags back, but I do want to keep these.

Can someone help me out fot those both cases? The language I'm using is php

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like an encoding issue. Make sure you have `<meta charset="utf-8">` right at the top of your `<head>` section

Comment: Well, as Phil says, doesn't need to be utf-8 though, but you should know what the returned character set of the API is, what character set you use yourself, and how to convert it to that character set if they're not the same. I prefer settings character sets in headers rather then in `<meta>` elements too.

Comment: @Wrikken Ah yes, I should have said *try* instead of *make sure*. I'm just used to working in unicode.

Comment: My excuses for the late response. The answer that made it work in my case was the 'utf-8' one in combination with 'htmlspecialchars()'.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- specify encoding in the header:

  ```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  ```

  ...
- encode string when handling the input

  $str=utf8_encode($str);
- if you are displaying the input back as-is, no encoding is required;
  however, if the value is the content of an input or textarea, escape the html characters

```
    <?php echo htmlspecialchars($str); ?>
```

Comment: You _do_ know `ut8_encode` is no silver-bullet function, and is design _only_ for converting from _ISO-8859-1_, and not a single other character set? (Although quite a few have a big overlap with ISO-8859-1, so it_seems_ to work for those inputs).

Comment: Yes, and no built-in PHP function is silver bullet. I use utf8_encode as the first line of defense, before passing it onto an extensive multi-byte encoding routine. My answer focuses more on the _where_ encoding should take place, rather than picking a "perfect" function. A correctly behaving program takes a systematic approach; I hope my answer saves someone some time.

Answer (score 0):

For Latin characters, use

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

in your  section.

Comment: it's not only a meta header issue, you need to have both the encoding of the text and the meta header to be the same, if you have the meta tag with latin1 spec and the text served by the web server is utf8 you will get scrambled text too

Answer (score 0):

you need to be sure about two things, the meta header referring to which enconding you will be using, and the encoding you are using for the text served.

If you are using a utf8 header just be sure to convert the text served to utf8, refer to functions for encoding conversion like : [mb_convert_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)